# SCCM 2012 - Windows 8 WSUS

Tags: windows, wsus, sccm

We're using SCCM 2012 to deploy Windows Updates on our domain, and our Windows 8 clients have started failing with error 80240438 when they try to update. Windows 7 clients update fine, but Windows 8 clients refuse to do anything. I've done a search online and it seems to only reference Windows InTune. Has anyone seen any similar behavior on Windows 8 machines? If we don't get that error, we're getting 80244021 which seems to indicate that the server can't be found.... but they can resolve it just fine and our exceptions are defined on the proxy too. A bit stuck here!

```
    2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    998 Agent   *********
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    998 Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    998 Agent   *************
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    998 Agent   WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x80240438
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {EAECB947-48AC-43BE-8F98-C44727E4A131} ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}]
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU    # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80240438
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU  #########
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {EAECB947-48AC-43BE-8F98-C44727E4A131} ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}]
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU  #############
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU  All AU searches complete.
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU    # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80240438
2012-11-22  14:45:28:935     476    c74 AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2012-11-22 04:12:23
2012-11-22  14:45:33:936     476    c9c Report  REPORT EVENT: {EE35CD79-FD2A-472D-BFC9-0420F5D60C04}    2012-11-22 14:45:28:935+1300    1   148 [AGENT_DETECTION_FAILED]    101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   80240438    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80240438.
2012-11-22  14:45:33:938     476    c9c Report  CWERReporter::HandleEvents - WER report upload completed with status 0x8
2012-11-22  14:45:33:938     476    c9c Report  WER Report sent: 7.8.9200.16420 0x80240438 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Scan 101 Managed
2012-11-22  14:45:33:938     476    c9c Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your WSUS to handle Windows 8 and added Win8 to the Product List?

See the following blog for details:

http://chapsnet.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/updating-your-wsus-for-windows-8-windows-server-2012/